# Aligning caption with figures in `subfigure` environment

Tags: graphics, floats, diagrams

I have the code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \captionsetup{format=hang,width=7cm}
  \caption{(a) dfdsfsdds.}
\quad
\subfigure[Neutral Smiley]{%
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{image.png}
\label{fig:subfigure1}}
\quad
\subfigure[Neutral Smiley]{%
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{image1.png}
\label{fig:subfigure1}}
\quad
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which gives something like
[image]

I'd like the "Figure" caption to lie on the left of these images, but still be inline with them. So something like:

[image]

Is there a way to do this within my `subfigure` environment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I have edited it, hope it helps!

Comment: Instead of using the `subfigure` package, which is deprecated, you should use either `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Comment: Sure, I changed everything to `\subfloat`. But my problem is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution via minipage. Package `subfig` and command `subfloat` still work with this format if preferred.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{Section one}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \captionsetup{format=hang,width=7cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
  \caption{(a) dfdsfsdds.}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
\subfigure[Neutral Smiley]{%
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\label{fig:subfigure1}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
\subfigure[Neutral Smiley]{%
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}
\label{fig:subfigure2}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonder why the OP manually inserted (a) in the main caption.